# Coupon Collector's Problem -- Expected Value of each item

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, coupon-collector

So I guess my problem is based on the famous coupon collector's problem, which is, if you should not be familiar with it, the following:

Given N different coupons from which coupons are being drawn independantly, with equal probability and with replacement: How many coupons do you expect to need to draw before having drawn each coupon at least once? ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem) has a well written article about it).

My problem is the following: I need to know what is the expected value for each coupon after we have collected at least one copy of each coupon.

More formal: We label each of the N coupons with numbers 1,...,n. Let $X_i$ be a random variable which counts how often we have drawn coupon $i$. What is $\mathbb{E}[X_i]$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expected value of the number of purchases until you have obtained the complete collection is $E_n=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\frac{n}{n-i+1}=n\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac1k$. For reasons of symmetry $E(X_i)=\frac{E_n}{n}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\frac1k$ for all $i$.

Answer (score 0):

A martingale solution:

Define the following game:

- Note the first coupon drawn $i_1$.
- A player enters and bet \$1. If a coupon $i_{2} \neq i_1$ is drawn he gets $\frac{N}{N-1}$, if not he loses his bet.
- If $i_2$ has been drawn at round $k$, the rule is now: bet 1, if the coupon drawn $i_{k+1}\not\in(i_1,i_2)$, win $\frac{N}{N-2}$.
- We continue similarly, that is $j$ coupons have been drawn, the prize is $\frac{N}{N-j}$.

Let denote $S_{t}$ the total gain of this game. We can easily show it is a martingale.

Define $\tau$ the stopping time where all coupons have beeen drawn once. Furthermore, we can show that $E[\tau]<\infty$. By the optional stopping theorem:
$$
E[S_{0}]=0=E[S_{\tau}]=-E[\tau]+\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}\frac{N}{N-k}
$$
Finally, we are looking for $$E[\tau]+1 = N\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\frac{N}{N-k}$$